# Code Sign Error - Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect

So I've spent the last week trying to solve the following error to no avail (even following the steps in my own answer to my own question from a little while ago

I've so far tried all manner of 'voodoo' solutions listed [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017756/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071691/xcode-error-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009981/xcode6-osx10-10-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777199/stuck-with-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-error), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124435/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1) all to no avail.

Please, if anyone can help me solve this issue, i would be eternally grateful.

I am trying to archive my app so i can submit it to the app store, but its falling down at the code signing.

```
CodeSign /Users/informationservices/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safer-Roads-Shellharbour-v2-afdgadppojkknjdzcvdqsvuxsmas/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Road\ Safety\ App\ V2/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Safer-Roads-Shellharbour-v2.app
    cd "/Volumes/App Development/IOS/App Development/Safer Roads Shellharbour 2.0/Safer Roads Shellharbour 2.0"
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: Information Services’s MacBook Pro (CG45JDQ5G7)"
Provisioning Profile: "iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: *"
                      (8bf314ed-8355-468c-82a9-37e2c46119a9)

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 66EB81FC3AA1D26BB39CBBB62AF4839298FCD362 --entitlements /Users/informationservices/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safer-Roads-Shellharbour-v2-afdgadppojkknjdzcvdqsvuxsmas/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Road\ Safety\ App\ V2/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Safer-Roads-Shellharbour-v2.build/Release-iphoneos/Safer-Roads-Shellharbour-v2.build/Safer-Roads-Shellharbour-v2.app.xcent /Users/informationservices/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safer-Roads-Shellharbour-v2-afdgadppojkknjdzcvdqsvuxsmas/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Road\ Safety\ App\ V2/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Safer-Roads-Shellharbour-v2.app

/Users/informationservices/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safer-Roads-Shellharbour-v2-afdgadppojkknjdzcvdqsvuxsmas/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Road Safety App V2/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Safer-Roads-Shellharbour-v2.app: User canceled the operation.
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be sure:

- your signing identity is a distribution ID? (it seems to be an developer cert)
- your prov. profile is active and not expired? and wildcard as a bundle id ist correct?
- your xcode-select path is correct (xcode-select -p)?
- moved the app somewhere and try to sign it there (perhaps some spaces in the path are mixing things up...)?

perhaps check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/TN2407/_index.html

Comment: Oh and was does build results (Build->Build Results) say?

Comment: it should be a distribution certificate that its using, I've created all new provisioning profiles and certificates, how do i check the xcode-select path? and i have tried moving the app to a couple of different places - nothing changes. and the Build fails.

Comment: It's not a distribution profile, because * (wildcard) is only allowed for development profiles and signing. so check if the profile is realy a distr. profile. the signing identity is called "developer" - is this really your cert for distribution? it does not seem so.

you can check the xcode-select path by opening terminal / iTerm an typing `xcode-select -p`.

Answer (score 0):

One place to also check is that in your Build Settings of your app, under Code Signing, you have your phone listed there under "Code Signing Identity". Default will only have iOS Developer, it should read your phone.