# Fixing Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

That the error xcode appear:

[image]

I had already tried that question no helpful:

[Code Sign Error - Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620038/code-sign-error-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)

I'm trying to upload an App from a not mine account.
I've imported the profile to Xcode.

I've the .mobileprovision for distribution and .p12 certificate already imported.

But when I try to archive I get the above error. 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, cleaning Derived folder, clean and Archive helps. If nothing helps, follow most common solution for computer science problem - Restart the MacBook and try again. It did work for me.

Comment: I had to restart the mac book. Thank you for reminding me of the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

> ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

Remove all old files, re-install the new profile,set the right profiles in

> code signing/provisioning profiles

Answer (score 0):

Man there is no issue with your code or pod files , i had face the same issue and the solution was to choose the right provisioning profile of my app

go to build settings --- code signing and under provisioning profile make sure that u chooed the right 1

BR